# Setting Up PostgreSQL for initial use on Mac OS

Tags: macos, postgresql

I've installed PostgreSQL 9 on my local mac and it installed the "SQL Shell (psql).app" which I assume is the command shell for the server.  I've opened it up but it asks for a `Username [postgres]:`.  I type in postgres and then it asks for a password.  I press enter and it gives the following error:
`psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

How do I log in and more importantly how do I run commands like `createdb`?  I tried the `createdb` command in my normal Terminal window but the command is not recognized.

Should I be using Homebrew or Macports? I haven't used either of these being new to the Mac OS

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What installation method did you use?

Comment: I downloaded and installed postgresql-9.0.4-1-osx.dmg

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and removing the host and port parameters from database.yml fixed it for me:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: my_db
  pool: 5
  host: localhost # remove this line
  port: 5432 # and this one
```

Answer (score 0):

If your postgres user doesn't have a password, set this env variable:

```
export PGPASSWORD=
```

Comment: where do I do this?  Sorry I am new to Unix in general